# Displaying a ui-grid inside a dialog box

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am actually using ui-grid to display some information on my page. Here is the basic structure :

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false" style="min-width:350px">
                <li style="text-align: center !important">
                    <label>SCHEDULE</label>
                </li>
                <li data-role="list-divider">
                    <div class="ui-grid-b">
                        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">Title 1</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">Title 2</div>
                        <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Title 3</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="ui-grid-b">
                            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">Info1</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">Info2</div>
                            <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Info3</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
</ul>
```

Now i want to have the same kind of structure inside dialog box. Here is how i initialise my dialog :

```
<div id="dialog" class="dialog" title="Parts">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false">
            <li data-role="list-divider">
                <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">Header Name</div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                        <div class="ui-block-a">Info1</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
(...)
</body>
<script>
$('#dialog').dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false,
    });
```

Then, inside a button, I activate the dialog with this line:

```
$('#dialog').dialog('open');
```

For some reason, the result isn't the same between a normal page and inside the dialog. Here is how it looks : On a normal page [image: On a normal page]

In the dialog box : [image]

I searched a lot about this and I can't find a solution. Any theory would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm using jQuery mobile 1.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jQM 1.3.x dialog is just a normal jQM page launched as a dialog:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-icon="false" style="min-width:350px">
            <li style="text-align: center !important">
                <label>SCHEDULE</label>
            </li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">
                <div class="ui-grid-b">
                    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">Title 1</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">Title 2</div>
                    <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Title 3</div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">
                   <div class="ui-grid-b">
                     <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:33%">Info1</div>
                     <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:34%">Info2</div>
                     <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:33%">Info3</div>
                   </div>
                 </a>   
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can then launch it from a link by setting data-rel="dialog":

```
<a href="#page2" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog</a>
```

or in code:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#page2", {
    role: "dialog"
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/10ugrzs5/)**

**UPDATE:**

Although you did not mention it or add a tag for it, it looks like you might be using the jQueryUI dialog, not the jQM dialog?  If so, put the dialog markup within your jQM data-role="page" div with display: none;. Then when you initialize the dialog, the UL will look like a jQM listview:

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/10ugrzs5/1/)**